# Making batch file to write batch file

Tags: batch-file

My question is 'How to write batch file in batch file,that will create new batch file when ran?'

Like this :

**echo systeminfo >>info.txt >>SystemInfo.bat**

I wan't new batch file (**SystemInfo.bat**) that will,when run create **Info.txt**,with system info in.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: what operating system is this in? what you are asking for doesn't quite make sense... you want to save systeminfo into a file named info.txt  when you run systeminfo.bat?

Comment: It is Windows,and this is batch file. When you run SYSTEMINFO.bat(That is create by other batch file),you get Info.txt file.That is what i want.This code doesn't work echo systeminfo >info.txt >>systeminfo.bat

Comment: @AhmedMasud: it makes sense, if he wants to put more than one command into the new batchfile (as ">>" implies)

Comment: Yes ,it's true.So SYSTEMINFO.bat should be like this "systeminfo >info.txt"

Comment: Only one slight enncy-weency problem with this. If you call your batch `systeminfo.bat` then in all likelihood, `systeminfo.bat` will be run by the command `systeminfo` - which will find the command `systeminfo` which will run `systeminfo.bat` which will find `systeminfo`... Just use another name - one that isn't an existing executable or `CMD` internal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will have to escape special chars:

```
echo systeminfo ^>^>info.txt >>SystemInfo.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this:    

@echo off    
echo Welcome    
echo > echo @echo off >> batchfilename.bat    
echo > echo echo hello >> batchfilename.bat    
echo > echo pause >> batchfilename.bat    

it will write the code to another batch file like batchfilename.bat    
(it will turn off echo, output hello and then pause so you can read it.)
```